# jsTree determine move between trees and change copied node ID

Tags: javascript, jstree, jstree-dnd

I'm trying to use jsTree to create 2 trees, based on parent-child relationships. To do this, I use the following script:

```
$(function () {

   loadTree($('#jstree_indexed_container'), document.getElementById('hiddenFieldIndexedData').value);
   loadTree($('#jstree_nonindexed_container'), document.getElementById('hiddenFieldNonIndexedData').value);

});

function loadTree(jsTreeContainer, stringData) {

   jsTreeContainer.jstree({

      "core": {
         "animation": 0,
         "check_callback": true,
         "themes": { "stripes": true },
         'data': JSON.parse(stringData)
      },
      "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "wholerow", "unique"]

   });

   jsTreeContainer.on("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
      notifyServerOfChange(data, false);
   });

   jsTreeContainer.on("copy_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
      notifyServerOfChange(data, true);
   });

}

function notifyServerOfChange(data, isCopy) {
   var oldParent = getNodeById(data.old_instance, data.old_parent);
   var newParent = getNodeById(data.new_instance, data.parent);

   alert(sprintf("%s node %s from %s to %s. It now has ID: %s", (isCopy ? "Copied" : "Moved"), (data.original != null ? data.original.id : data.node.id), getNodeTitle(oldParent), getNodeTitle(newParent), data.node.id));
}

function getNodeById(jsTreeContainer, id) {
   return jsTreeContainer.element.find("[id='" + id + "']");
}

function getNodeTitle(node) {
   return node.find('a').first().text();
}
```

However, when moving a node between the 2 trees, the "copy_node.jstree" event is always invoked, even though I'm moving the node. If I move the node in the same tree, I get the correct "move_node.jstree" event.

**Question 1:** Is there a way of correctly determining if the node was moved, rather than copied, between 2 trees?

**Question 2:** My node IDs are computed based on the parent-child relationship, so after copying / moving a node, I recompute this relationship and I want to use it to replace the previous ID of the node. If I try to modify the data.node.id in the ***notifyServerOfChange*** method, the node can no longer be selected afterwards.

Thank you

Comment: Solved Question 2 by using data.instance.set_id in the notifyServerOfChange method like this: if (data.original) data.instance.set_id(data.node, data.original.id + "_1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move nodes between trees with drag n drop (as it goes from the plugins you use) you can listen to `dnd_stop.vakata` event and check if `ctrl` key is pressed like this:

```
$(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function (e, data) {
    if (data.event.ctrlKey) {
        console.log('copy');
    } else {
        console.log('move');
    }
 });
```

Check fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ubo3tjzk/)